# How to reshape, fill and transpose a matrix correctly and memory friendly

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I am struggling with data manipulation of a large single-column data as can be seen here [testo.dat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11g1Y_QRr3dgto27x0AvN0hKo0njFqEN0) (google Drive thinks that this file is a video but 1.6Mb data file -don't worry). The code I did so far works partly as you can review below.

I am trying following things with my input:

1. Load the text and store into an 1d array - that works fine
2. Create a matrix by reshaping based on the length of the 1d array - that works fine too
3. **Fill the values from the single array into the new created matrix so that the data will be arranged on a grid/matrix with the desired numbers for row and column - And here is my actual problem!**
4. Finally transpose the matrix - this works fine if I would have a filled matrix

So my questions are: Does the part with the matrix filling (point #3) makes sense at all because it stuck with the first line of the 1d array ?. I saw in other post methods like "slice" and "split"  -are those applicable here ?

Any help is greatly appreciated

### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 1. Load a file with a single column and store into an array 
data = np.loadtxt('testo.dat',skiprows=3) 
bz_array = data[:]                        


# 2. Prepare the matrix by setting up rows and cols which matchs the    length of data
rows = 20
cols = 3600
n=len(data)                              
if (n == (rows*cols)):
    print "rows*cols == length of data" 

# 3. Create the matrix 
shape = (rows,cols) # 72000 lines/20 = 3600 columns
bz_matrix = np.arange(n).reshape(shape)
if np.shape(bz_matrix) == shape:
    print "shape is ok"

# 4. How to fill this matrix with minimum of memory and cpu ? 
line=0

while line < n:
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(rows):
            bz_matrix=bz_array[line]
            print bz_matrix
    line+=line


# 5. Transpose the matrix 
bz_matrix_transposed = bz_matrix.transpose()
if (np.shape(bz_matrix_transposed) == (cols,rows)):
    print "transposed shape is ok" 

# 6. I would like to have also a printed file of the transposed matrix
f = open('out.dat', 'w') 
np.savetxt(f, bz_matrix_transposed, fmt='%10.5f') 


# 7. plot a 2D graph of the transposed matrix,
plt.imshow(bz_matrix_transposed((cols,rows)));
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What actually do you want to accomplish? Read data, reshape it to `20x3600` matrix and then transpose it? If so, then instead of steps 3 and 4 you should just reshape your `data` and that's it.

Comment: Wow, your right I actually did not know how powerful that reshape thing is ! I just tried it and it did what I wanted to do. Thought I had to create first an "empty" matrix and then get the values from the initial array into it. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update the code above. Thanks to Georgy (Jan-19,2018), I could see where the actual problem was.

```
# 1. Load a file with a single column and store into an array 
data = np.loadtxt('testo.dat',skiprows=3) 
bz_array = data[:]                        


# 2. Prepare the matrix by setting up rows and cols which matchs the                 length of data
rows = 20
cols = 3600
n=len(data)                              
if (n == (rows*cols)):
    print "rows*cols == length of data" 

# 3. Create the matrix 
shape = (rows,cols) # 72000 lines/20 = 3600 columns
bz_array.shape=(shape)


# 5. Transpose the matrix 
bz_matrix_transposed = bz_array.transpose()
if (np.shape(bz_matrix_transposed) == (cols,rows)):
    print "transposed shape is ok" 


# 6. I would like to have the finnished data as a seperate file 
bz_finnished = np.asarray(bz_matrix_transposed).ravel()
f = open('out_finnished', 'w') 
np.savetxt(f, bz_finnished, fmt='%10.5f')
```